# Telegram бот 'слушающий' Чат в котором бот администратор

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть телеграм канал (Чат), в котором бот, написанный на языке python, администратор.

При появлении не желаемого сообщения в Чате (например адрес сайта), бот должен удалить сообщение. Но для этого нужно знать когда появляется сообщения в канале и его `message_id`.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.channel_post_handler(content_types=['text'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используете **pyTelegramBotAPI**

То можно получать текст каждого сообщения и при помощи какого нибудь регулярного выражения искать в них адреса сайтов и после этого уже удалять сообщение.

Если не ошибаюсь есть функция

```
bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: ну да, а как взять именно id сообщения в чате?

Comment: @Hayk Sardaryan так в message передаётся все эта информация, просто каждое сообщение проверяйте на наличие ссылок и удаляйте если обнаружите!

Answer (score 1):

Опять же, если используется pyTelegramBotAPI, то обычный декоратор перехвата можно настроить, чтоб перехватывались вообще все сообщения:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
```

ну а в функции парсите все id какие нужно:

```
def catch_all(message):
    print(message.from_user.id)
    print(message.message_id)
    print(message.chat.id)
```

Comment: мне надо написать в чате в чате в чате  в чате в чате в чате а не боту